# What does 'walk-through' mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> Jane : Hi Mateo, Brian Jaffers just called to cancel tomorrow's
>   **walk-through** at 721 Union Street. 
>  Mateo : That's too bad. That
>   apartment is just right for him. Did you reschedule?

I nearly understand what they're saying, but I'd like to want to know what exactly 'walk-through' means 
A dictionary only shows the word means something related to rehearsal.
But I think the meaning of the word is related to real estate industry, doesn't it?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the real estate sense:  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/225278?rskey=m55BHA&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> a. Chiefly N. Amer. A **walk through** somewhere or something for the
>   purposes of inspection or surveillance; an inspection carried out on
>   foot, esp. of a home or other premises, spec. one conducted prior to
>   finalizing the sale of a property.

As in:

> 2005   J. P. DiBlasi *Sell Home without Broker*    Your
>   Purchase and Sale Agreement..will allow the buyer to take a last
>   **walk-through** of your home..prior to closing.